# Every time I start Ubuntu it shows Error message

Tags: startup, error-handling

Each time I start Ubuntu I get an error message saying

> Sorry Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error

I have attached a screen shot of the error
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUtYx.png)

Comment: Disregard my last message.  I actually just installed it, and I get exactly the same.  That application should not be needed.  `sudo apt-get remove indicator-keyboard`